# Is an EXCLUSIVE lock the only way to prevent multiple sessions from simultaneously inserting?

Tags: sql, oracle, concurrency, insert

I'm thinking about implementing a queue in an Oracle database basically using a table as the queue and am trying to decide how to prevent multiple sessions from inserting into the table at the same time and messing up the ordering.

Is doing a `LOCK TABLE mytable IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` the only way to prevent multiple sessions from inserting into a table?

Edit:

"Queue" is probably not the right term here. More of a list, in which the relative order between the elements is what's important. I'm thinking of something on the order of Java's [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure you need to implement your own queue?  Oracle provides [built-in queuing (called Oracle Advanced Queuing)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm).  That would certainly tend to be a better option than implementing the same thing yourself.

If you do implement a queue yourself, why would you need to prevent concurrent inserts?  What order are you concerned with being "messed up"?  Assuming you are using an Oracle sequence object to populate the primary key, I don't see any reason that you'd have to prevent concurrent updates.

Comment: I was going to post the same thing.  If you don't want to lock, then you queue.

Comment: Oracle AQ appears to be purely FIFO and I'd like to be able to rearrange items in the queue as priorities change. From what I've read in the docs, I only see ways to enqueue and dequeue, not change the location of an element in the queue or delete an arbitrary element.

Comment: @eaolson - AQ supports priority queues as well http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qsample.htm#64828

Answer (score 1):

It's completely unclear to me what problem you're trying to avoid.

Explicit locking provides serialization, but doesn't seem to provide any meaningful, deterministic order of insertion.  If two sessions tried to insert "at the same time", which one gets the lock first is essentially random.  You'd get the same effect without explicit locking if the table has a primary key, since multiple inserts would have to serialize on that to enforce uniqueness.  But even without that, one session would end up inserting (or more to the point, committing its insert) before the other.

It sounds like you have some sense of an order the items need to be in, independently of the order in which they are inserted.  Without more detail, my reaction to that is that the table should have a column that indicates the ordering, and readers of the table should make use of that to properly sort the records.  Recall that database tables have no inherent ordering; just because one row is inserted before another does not mean that they are stored in that order or returned to queries in that order.

Comment: Forcing an order to the rows with a numeric column is exactly what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @ealoson -- so, don't worry about the order in which the rows are inserted.  When you select rows from the table, ORDER BY the numeric column.  If you really want to enforce a physical storage ordering on the rows, an index-organized table might be effective, but I really don't see any reason that is beneficial.

Comment: Session 1: Insert item #3, Session 2: Insert item #3, Session 1: Commit, Session 2: Commit. That's what I'm trying to avoid. I'm not really worried about physical storage order, just about maintaining the ordering of the rows.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to force session 2's insert to block until session 1 commits?  Perhaps setting the transaction isolation level to serializable is what you really want.  But I still do not see why you want to avoid it.  What bad thing happens as a result?  Perhaps another solution would be to include an insertion timestamp in the rows, and include that in the ordering when querying the table.

Comment: Well the bad thing is that now I have two #3 items. Serializable doesn't stop that, either. I'm just trying to create an ordered list of items where users can insert and delete items, as well as reorder the list as priorities change.

Comment: If you don't want to have two items with number 3, put a unique constraint on that column in the table.